# Benchmarking Apache using Specweb 2009

Tags: linux, apache, webserver, benchmarking

I am bench marking Apache `2.2` performance using `Specweb2009` specifically by using the `support` workload. I want to load the server so as to make it execute at high CPU load.

The issue is when I run the test using 10 Apache server processes and 25 load clients the test fails with the errors like `HTTPRequestSched: [ERROR] Bad response (-1). Request was GET /support/downloads/dir0000000019/download5_0 HTTP/1.1
SPECweb_Support: [ERROR] STATE 6; makeHttpRequest() failed.
Connection: [ERROR] Bad status: 404` and still the CPU usage for the `Apache` processes reaches maximum of `0.7 %`.

On the other hand if I use more `Apache` processes like 20 and client load processes 25 my test passes the `QOS` without nay errors but the `CPU %` for `Apache` still only touches maximum of `0.7%`.

My understanding is that in the first case `Apache` processes are loaded heavily so they are not able to send the responses but in that case they should show high `CPU` utilization but they are not.

Am I missing something in the config files?

I will really appreciate if any one can suggest any good links or just suggest some config changes to rectify the issue.

Some of my config files are:

[httpd-mpm.conf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49309742/httpd-mpm.conf)

[httpd.conf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49309742/httpd.conf)

[SPECweb_Support.config](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49309742/SPECweb_Support.config)

[Test.config](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49309742/Test.config)

Thanks

Comment: Why did you give a us a link to your httpd.conf when all the capacity and performance config is held in other files? (although by the looks of things there's been no signifcant effort to address performance).

Comment: @symcbean I provided all the conf files in the case if I have missed anything in one of them. I am new to bench marking for performance. I already tried searching for the issue but could not find any specific solution for this. Can you please suggest some changes that I could do to achieve this or pointers to any resource which could help me. apologies for my naivety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do know that SpecWeb2009 is retired now?

Having said that, the last time I set up for this was a few years ago, and from what I remember, to get it working, you had to follow the recommended steps carefully (verifying as you go along). In particular, you need to setup for an entire Specweb suite test, else it's pointless and you might as well use apache bench or something else.

In terms of documentation/guidelines, I found that looking through reports worked best in showing how the various elements were setup.  [This is a typical report](http://www.spec.org/web2009/results/res2012q1/web2009-20120112-00010.html), scroll down and read the Notes (HTTP Software Notes).  That was an IBM originated report, and they discuss a little bit how they configured for apache in [this PDF report](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/linux/pdfs/Tuning_for_Web_Serving_on_RHEL_64_KVM.pdf) (see around page-14 forwards).

So, on the whole, I would say:

- ensure you have a good set of guides
- be prepared to configure for the whole suite, or seek another benchmarking solution
- go through various reports and compare their configs with what you have.
- don't be reluctant to start over when things don't seem to be working.

Some documentation links:

- a [specweb2009 suggested design document](http://www.spec.org/web2009/docs/design/SPECweb2009_Design.html)
- of course, the [spec2009 user manual](https://www.spec.org/web2009/docs/usersguide.html) (in case you haven't seen it)
- [this is a chinese site](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_8588208901018ewb.html) (i think) but the config directives are in english
- [this brief paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~bernard/systor12-final58.pdf) talks webserver benchmarking methodologies (seems a useful quick ref)

Hope you find this useful ..